# Awesomium offscreen rendered to Leadwerks texture

Tags: awesomium

I'm using the Leadwerks game engine and I'm trying to get Awesomium to render to a Leadwerks Texture but having no luck. Below is the code where I create a texture, allocate unsigned char* variable that I put the Awesomium surface into via CopyTo() then set that variable to the LEadwerks Texture but the screen stays black so clearly I'm not understanding something here. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

```
Texture* uiTex = Texture::Create(window->GetWidth(), window->GetHeight());
unsigned char* pixels = (unsigned char*)malloc(uiTex->GetMipmapSize(0));

// copy surface to LE texture and draw that texture to screen
BitmapSurface* surface = static_cast<BitmapSurface*>(view->surface());
surface->CopyTo(pixels, 1024, 32, true, false);
uiTex->SetPixels((char*)pixels);

context->DrawImage(uiTex, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if some unlucky bastard like myself stumble upon this in the future there might as well be a little guidance.

Begin by checking that everything has been setup correctly in Awesomium. Otherwise it will seem fine but the surface returned will simply be null.

Save the Awesomium surface to file and inspect to verify that it gets generated in the first place.